# Generate dynamic views by parsing an XML

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, ios, ipad

I can parse an XML file using `NSXMLParser`. I can also get the tags and the attributes. However, my XML has tags like **Textfield,Label ,Picker**.
I want to bring these controls dynamically into my view.

Also, I want to display a different view after getting a `<Page>` tag.  How can I display a different view?

Are there any tutorials for this?

Comment: Got any examples you can share of the XML files you're trying to use?

Comment: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FormConfig>
 <Form>Contact</Form>
 <property>
  <row>
   <type>textbox</type>
   <label>FName</label><value></value>
  </row>
  <row>
   <property>Checkbox</property>
   <label>Contact Preference</label>        <values>Email,Phone</values>
  </row>
  
 </property>
</FormConfig>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably best that you understand how views work before you try to parse an XML file to determine what views to place.

You can add a view to the view hierarchy with `addSubview:`. You create the new view with `[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:buttonFrame]`.

You can find tons of documentation on how that works over at http://developer.apple.com;

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html